# Is it possible to add/create Bing Map control to DevExpress Reports?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Is it possible to add Bing Map control to DevExpress Reports? Or, even to generate one at  the runtime?

I need a report with map control with set of pushpins using DevExpress reports. If not possible using DevEx reporting tool, can it be done in any other way?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Well, I have been trying other options without success. As for DevEx I do not see any MapControl available.

Comment: @Learner There are several DevExpress MapControls: for [WPF/Silverlignt](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Map/) and for [WinForms](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Map/). As far as i know, there is no direct way to add mapcontrol into XtraReport. To print/export map you can try possible approach described in the following ticket: [Print / Export Maps](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q386207).

Comment: @Learner Anyway it is better to [ask this question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) in the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).